# send email in hangfire with postal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, hangfire

I'm using hangfire and for DI using autofac. i want to send email with postal.mvc5 tools and i got this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException

The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext is not available.

System.InvalidOperationException: The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext is not available.
   at Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RequestLifetimeScopeProvider.GetLifetimeScope(Action`1 configurationAction)    
   at Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.get_RequestLifetimeScope()
   at Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.DefaultViewPageActivator.Create(ControllerContext controllerContext, Type type)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.RenderView(IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ControllerContext controllerContext, ImageEmbedder imageEmbedder)
   at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.Render(Email email, String viewName)
   at Postal.EmailService.Send(Email email)
   at Postal.Email.Send()
   at Store.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Test() in C:\Users\a\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\In\S.Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 33
```

i search 2 days and nothing found about this problem. please help me! Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Autofac.Mvc5 package?

Comment: Where are you invoking `HomeController.Test()` from? a unit test or from the browser?

Comment: @Tom Redfern yes i use this

Comment: @Yacoub Massad from browser

Comment: Can you give more context? For example can you show the Test method in the controller? And the URL that you use to communicate with the site?

Comment: Sorry for delay. sure

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue<Postal.EmailService>(s => s.Send(new Email("Test")
            {
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary
                {
                    {"From", "test@gmail.com"},
                    {"To", "test@ymail.com"}
                }
            }));

            return View();
        }

Comment: container.RegisterFilterProvider();
container.RegisterControllers(allAssemblies);
container.RegisterModelBinders(allAssemblies);
container.RegisterAssemblyModules(allAssemblies);
container.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();
var build = container.Build();
JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseHangfireServer(JobStorage.Current, new BackgroundJobServerOptions
{Activator = new AutofacJobActivator(build)});
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(build));

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/send-email.html#installing-postal

as explanation from link above. You can't use Viewbag or template for sending email outside httpcontext. You must use Model instead Viewbag, and embedded image cannot also (refer to http://aboutcode.net/postal/outside-aspnet.html)

For embedded image you can pass through model , see here for more explanation https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal/issues/44